# NHibernate MySQL Enum

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, nhibernate, enums

I am trying to access the "MYSQL" database tables to create a GUI for adding users and privileges.

Doing this, I have run into my first NHibernate problem. How do i map MySQL Enum's to a C# Boolean? Or if not possible then to at least a Enum?

The database fields are delcared as

```
enum('N', 'Y')
```

These are all of the privilege fields in the database.

Now is there anyway of getting this into an enum or even better, **boolean** in C#/NHibernate?

**Edit #1:** In C# if I need to declare an enum it will be the following:

```
enum YesNoEnum
{
  Yes,
  No
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring your C# enum?

Comment: I would prefer it be a boolean, but please see Edit #1: above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bool in C# and map it to a char in MySQL using a custom IUserType implementation. [This example](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that :D I found from that post that YesNoType is actually built into NHibernate (At least the version I'm using 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using MySQL's enum with NHibernate, but I do know that if you want to use a boolean field in C# and have it mapped to a MySQL database, you can do this:

MyDto.cs:

```
public bool IsAdmin {get;set;}
```

Column definition in the database:

```
`IsAdmin` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: This wont work, I am trying to access the built in MySQL privilege tables. THerefore i cannot change/create schema/column definition.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, can't help you then :(